# .Net Core Jwt Authentication How To Use Single Token Across Multiple Applications

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have two separate projects let's say project A and project B. One of them (project A) is the main project with a authentication service using Jwt Authentication. The other one is the dependent application.

Both are separate web api applications and uses different version of .net framework.

I need to validate single token in both applications and also need policies registered at project A.

Is there any easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: Are the apps on the same domain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367938/sharing-authentication-between-asp-net-and-asp-net-core  You can take a look.  Maybe It would help you to improve solving the problem.

Comment: You could use identity server or Azure AD to achieve your requirement. For example, you could ask a token from the identity server or AAD provider, then this token could access all the projects which the AAD or identity server has protected.